# How to open .dmg file or install XCode on Windows?

Tags: windows, xcode, dmg

I am mostly windows developer and had to step into iDevelopmentWorld.
Went [to apple to get XCode](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_6.3.2/Xcode_6.3.2.dmg), downloaded it, however file extension is `.dmg`. Windows does not recognize it as executable and throws following dialog.

[image]

I am guessing that ether
1. I need some additional software to open it (like mounting an image).
or
2. `.dmg` is not for windows but iOS and I am out of luck.

Comment: Xcode runs under OS X, buy a Mac.

Comment: Hacker News has a reasonable discussion about [using Xcode in a virtual environment](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9644773). Those who have tried, suggest buying a Mac.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can **not** install XCode on any version of Windows, it only runs on OS X.

Comment: Not entirely true there's an option of installing Virtual OS X on Windows and go from there. http://lifehacker.com/5938332/how-to-run-mac-os-x-on-any-windows-pc-using-virtualbox

Comment: Correct, I wouldn't call it running on Windows though in that case :-)

Comment: @Matas Vaitkevicius, Installing OS X in a VM under Windows is not allow by its SLA and no company that produces a Type 2 Hypervisor officially supports installing OS X in a VM under anything other then OS X!

Answer (score 0):

I figured that it's archive and [extracted it with 7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html). However couldn't find any executables inside. My guess is I need to run `3.hfs` but it's different question.

[image]

Comment: _.dmg_ files are an Apple Disk Image file and typically not needed to be accessed under Windows however [HFSExplorer](http://www.catacombae.org/hfsexplorer/) and [DMGExtractor](http://www.catacombae.org/dmgextractor/) can be helpful under Windows if needed.

Answer (score 0):

https://blog.udemy.com/xcode-on-windows/

Check out that website, you can simulate Mac OS X on windows and therefore run Xcode

Comment: The [SLA](https://www.apple.com/legal/sla/) for OS X **does not allow** for it to be virtualized on non-Apple hardware!